# Why should I use GetOriginalEntityState() in my LINQ To SQL repository save method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm looking at an example of a save method in a Products repository from Steven Sanderson's book, Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework:

```
public void SaveProduct(Product product)
{
    // if new product, attach to DataContext:
    if (product.ProductID == 0)
        productsTable.InsertOnSubmit(product);
    else if (productsTable.GetOriginalEntityState(product) == null)
    { 
        // we're updating existing product
        productsTable.Attach(product);
        productsTable.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, product);
    }
    productsTable.Context.SubmitChanges();            
}
```

I do not understand the logic in the `else if` line:

```
else if (productsTable.GetOriginalEntityState(product) == null)
```

As I understand it,  `GetOriginalEntityState()` returns the original state of the specified entity.. in this case that entity is `product`.

So this else if statement reads to me like: *"If an original doesn't exist then..."* but that doesn't make sense because the book is saying that this checks that we are modifying a record that already DOES exist.

How should I understand `GetOriginalEntityState` in this context?

#### Edit

By the way, this excerpt came from chapter 6, page 191... just in case anyone has the book and wants to look it up. The book just has that function in the code sample but it never explains what the function does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little bit of a guess since I have never actually used `GetOriginalEntityState` but the question peaked my interest to figure out what is going on.

I think the intent here is to check that `product` is still attached to the original `DataContext`

The line:

```
if (productsTable.GetOriginalEntityState(product) == null)
```

I think this will return null if `product` has been dettached or created manually and not handled by the `DataContext`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548700.aspx):

> This method returns the original state
>   of an entity since it was either
>   created or attached to the current
>   DataContext. The original state of an
>   entity that has been serialized and
>   deserialized must be provided by an
>   independent tracking mechanism and
>   supplied when the entity is attached
>   to a new DataContext. For more
>   information, see Data Retrieval and
>   CUD Operations in N-Tier Applications
>   (LINQ to SQL).

I think the key line to understand is:

> This method returns the original state
>   of an entity since it was either
>   created or attached to the current
>   DataContext.

`GetOriginalEntityState` is used so that the method can receive an object with the option of not being attached already to the `DataContext`. Attached meaning, returned by a Linq To SQL call vs just creating an instance like `Product p = new Product() { ... };`.  If it is not attached, it will attach it to the `DataContext` and keep any of the values that were modified (preserving the update values) due to the `RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues` param.

Then the `productsTable.Context.SubmitChanges();` always happens since even if it is dettached, the `GetOriginalEntityState` will make sure it gets attached so the submit will work.

Comment: Thanks for doing the leg work on my question! So, to clarify, the first if `if(product.ProductID == 0)` checks to see if it's new or existing. The else/if `else if (productsTable.GetOriginalEntityState(product) == null)` checks to see if the product has been associated with the corresponding row in the table... if not then it associates it by attaching. Then, changes are submitted. Do I have that right?

Comment: @quakkels That is how I understanding it but like I said, I have not actually tested it to verify.

Comment: That makes sense... I'm trying to figure out what situation would cause `else if (productsTable.GetOriginalEntityState(product) == null` to return false.

Comment: I tested this and Kelsey is bang on.

Comment: @JohnnyO lucky guess by me :P